# How high a mesh count do fine details require?

Tags: screen-printing

I'm having trouble reproducing fine lines on my 155 mesh screen. I wonder: is it because the mesh count is too low, or is it likely something else? And if we suspect a higher mesh count would fix it, is there a way to tell what mesh would be best?

Looking at the screen, the lines I want to draw are not much more than one "mesh pixel" across, which feels a bit tight. Is there a rule of thumb about this? On the other hand, my setup is pretty janky---I'm using the "oil method" with a hand-drawn (rather than printed) design, and exposing in the sun (this is Diazo emulsion exposed in direct sunlight for 20 seconds). I'm suspicious also whether the oil method is good for reproducing fine details, or if exposing in the sun is too imprecise on account of the fast exposure time.

For reference, I'm planning to print water-based ink on paper---for postcards, so it's quite small.

Pictures to illustrate the problem: close-ups of the screen (with the mesh visible) showing where lines haven't reproduced well, and the design with the corresponding sections marked to show scale.

[image: silkscreen closeup 1]
[image: silkscreen closeup 2]
[image: original design]

I've asked the same question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCREENPRINTING/comments/gy1e6d/mesh_count_issue_or_something_else/).